# Перевод из одного формата чисел в другой формат. Python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re, формат

у меня есть список цифр ['1','2','3','56'] мне необходимо перевести их в формат 0001 0002 0003 0056, возможно ли это реализовать с помощью регулярных выражений?

Comment: Обыкновенный парсинг **чисел** (а не цифр), при помощи `\d`, затем добивать ведущими нулями, если цифр в числе меньше четырёх

Comment: Возможно. А можете, пожалуйста, добавить в вопрос ваши попытки решения задачи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы для решения этой задачи воспользовался возможностью форматирования строк:

```py
formatted_number = [f"{number:0>4}" for number in ['1','2','3','56']]
```

Краткое объяснение моего решения: `f"{x :%заполнитель% %куда выравнивать% %минимальная длинна строки%}"`

Получше об форматировании строк можно почитать [здесь](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/formatirovanie-strok-metod-format.html).

Comment: Просили же - "с помощью регулярных выражений".

Comment: Я не понимаю, для чего они нужны в этой задачи. Уже дан список цифр в массиве. А регулярные выражения нужны для поиска данных в строке. Поправьте меня, если я не прав.

Comment: Это вопрос отнесите автору.